# Как записать в разные ID ответ от сервера

Tags: php, ajax

перебрасываю данные с БД Аяксом на страницу Html

```
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function(){
     $.ajax({
          url: "test.php" ,
          type:'GET',
          //dataType: "json",
          cache: false,
    success:function(data){
   $('#olm').html(data);
   console.log(data);
}
    });
}, 15000);
```

PHP

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `work`";
   $result = $mysqli->query($sql); 
   // В цикле перебираем все записи таблицы и выводим их
   while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
   {

       echo 'TITLE:  '.$row['work']."<br/>"; 
       echo 'SOCIAL: '.$row['title']."<br/>";
       echo 'TEXT: '.$row['text']."<br/>";
       echo 'TIME:   '.$row['time']."<br/>";


   }
```

В ID olm все выводится одним блоком, Собственно вопрос: Реально это все раскидать по разным ID т.е допустим `echo 'TITLE:  '.$row['work']."<br/>";` 
Записать в #olm, а вторую строчку `echo 'SOCIAL: '.$row['title']."<br/>";`
допустим в id olm2 ?
Спасибо.

Comment: думаю тебе лучше отправить данные в виде   json   и,  распарсить на клиенте его будет проще

Answer (score 0):

например можно  на сервере `echo json_encode(['title'=>$row['work'],'social'=>$row['title'],'text'=>$row['text'],'time'=>$row['time']]);`

на клиенте:

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
        function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "test.php",
                type: 'GET',
                //dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    data = JSON.parse(data);

                    $('#olm').html('TITLE:' + data.work + '<br/>');
                    $('#olm2').html('SOCIAL:' + data.title + '<br/>');
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }, 15000);
```

делается так для того что бы  например сформировать сложный объект данных для отправки клиенту на сервере, а на клиенте уже получить их и использовать как минимум так как ты хочешь... (то есть получить не просто html,  а какие то сущности  и применять их в логике на клиентеби вывод полученных данных чаще всего в таких ситуациях формируют на клиенте)

Comment: Сергей, спасибо буду пробовать)

Comment: data = JSON.parse(data);

                 ругается на синтаксическую ошибку, в консоль ответ приходит

Comment: закомментируй это  и посмоттри что выводится в consoe.log

Comment: приходит json ответ от сервера

Comment: {"title":"1","social":"Youtube","text":"www.yrtyrsh","time":"14:19:21"}

Comment: короче ответ пришел без скобок, значит пользуйся так , без JSON.parse.

Comment: Пишет TITLE:undefined непосредственно в id

Comment: хотя в логах все хорошо

Comment: а console.log(data.title)?

Comment: все то же undefined видимо не раскодируется

Comment: а попробуй  например data['title'] ?

Comment: teamviewer  есть?

Comment: к сожалению нет, возьму таймаут)), может туплю где

Comment: если совсем не пойдет..ставь себе на ком  teamviewer. подрублюсь, посмотрю что у тебя за проблемы. хотя все должно быть просто.

Comment: да , и попробуй вместо  get  post -запрос

Comment: Сергей, я немного обманул Вас, ответ от сервера был не json а просто echo, теперь получаю чистый json массив в [ ] скобках, вот как его распарсить?...

Comment: data = JSON.parse(data);  постоянно ошибка синтаксиса